# optimize mysqldump output for zfs dedup

Tags: linux, backup, mysql, zfs

My challenge is to store as many mysql dumps as possible on a given ZFS pool.

The pool itself has **dedup and compression enabled**. For storing multiple versions of the dumps snapshots are used (every 15 min, every hour, every day, every week and every month).

Most of the tables in the various databases on the MySQL Server are growing and do not change very often. My thinking was to do a dump per table instead of per database to give zfs a chance to dedup on block-level.

The backup script uses the output of mysqldump and pipes it to a file (with `mysqldmup -u$user -p$pass $db $table > $outputfile.sql`

- Is ZFS dedup able to dedup a stream from stdout at a good rate?
- Should the blocksize of the destination datased be configured manually? (and if yes - which size?)
- Shoud some sort of output buffering (other than line buffering) be applied?
- Are the writes from a redirect sync or async?

EDIT to nail it down: What is necessary to make a file written line by line dedup like a file that was copied if contents are (almost [eg. only last line differs]) the same?

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "Are the writes from a redirect sync or async?" in this case?

Comment: Does a console redirect to a file cause a sync write or an async write in ZFS? If the buffer is flushed line by line then each write could be a few bytes. If each line causes a write in ZFS the blocks of the actual written file will change very often resulting in unnecessary writes and/or dedup checksum calculations. (EDIT: this could be mitigated with `zfs set sync=disabled poolname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduplication is always at block level (as are snapshots and copmression), the structure of the data above does not matter. Therefore, you could have a single file instead of thousand small files and it would not make a difference in regards to deduplication.

On the other hand, your block size does make a difference, because of several reasons:

- The bigger your blocks are, the more waste can occur because a some bytes of a very small file can reserve the size of a large block (your block size is the smallest unit and cannot be divided further)
- The smaller your blocks are, the slower your performance will be on average, because to read the same file, you now have to read many more blocks (each read having a slight overhead and each block might very well be on a completely different position on the whole disk)
- Deduplication works on blocks, so a small size would possibly get better results
- On the other hand, this increases the number of blocks that have to referenced in memory and may degrade your performance. For the trade-off and example calculations, see [this blog post](http://constantin.glez.de/blog/2011/07/zfs-dedupe-or-not-dedupe) - the essential takeaway is that you need a large amount of memory and that it depends on your data

Sizing is therefore important, but also [not that easy](https://blogs.oracle.com/roch/tuning-zfs-recordsize). It seems you already have enough data, so I would just test it: create two filesystems (if possible afterwards and not simultaneously to minimize effect on each other), one with a very small block size (4K), one with a very big size (128K) and then copy your data and compare the results. You also can simulate deduplication performance with `zdb -b poolname` by comparing both block counts and then calculating your savings. If neither of those results look good to you, try different sizes like 16K, 32K, or 64K.

Comment: Before i touched this task the backup was done with `mysqldump --database` which produced one file per database and caused very bad dedup ratio (1.12). Only marginal changes in length of a table changed all following blocks in the backup file.

Comment: The Oracle document at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gkknx.html says that `When a file is written, the data is compressed, encrypted, and the checksum is verified. Then, the data is deduplicated, if possible.`. If the FILE is compressed first, then subsequent data blocks will change if only slight changes are made. Is this (still) true?